# Prove. $e^{2x^2-\sin^2(x\pi)} = 5$ has a solution in $(0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm a student taking a real analysis course at university and I've been working on the problems on my problem sheet. I've been asked the above question.

The expression itself is almost unbearable to a simple 2nd year student like myself. I assume the Intermediate Value Theorem needs to be used but I'm having trouble even finding one solution where $e^{2x^2-\sin^2(x\pi)} = 5$ let alone in $(0,1)$.

Any tips or tricks on how to unpack this would be much appreciated!

Comment: $f(0)=1<5$ and $f(1)>5$. Use IVP.

Comment: Proving the existence of a solution doesn't mean finding one explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=e^{2x^2-\sin^2(x\pi)}$.

Then $f$ is defined for all real $x$ and is continuous in the interval $(0,1)$.

$f(0)=1$ and $f(1)\approx7.389>5$.

Hence, by the intermediate value theorem (IVT), there must be some $a\in(0,1)$ such that $f(a)=5$.

So $e^{2x^2-\sin^2(x\pi)}=5$ has a solution in $(0,1)$.

Note that in your question, proving that $f(x)=5$ has a solution does not mean that you need to actually find it, you just need to show that it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Define the function $f(x) = e^{(2x^2-sin(x\pi)^2} -5 $
Use the Intermediate Value Theorem on $f(x)$. When can you say it's negative and when positive?